# R Spark read one file at a time from folder, integrate with Shiny

Tags: r, windows, apache-spark, shiny, sparklyr

I have a folder on HDFS which contains 10 CSV files. Each CSV file contains 10000 rows and 17 columns.

**Objective**

Reactively read a folder on HDFS.

If the folder contains files, read one file at a time (oldest to newest) from the folder.

Plot some parameters in Shiny.

Update plot as new files are added to the folder or read from the folder.

**Status** Currently, with SparklyR, I am able to reactively read all files at once and generate a plot containing 100000 points ([ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6dmr.png)). If I add an 11th file (containing 10000 rows) after starting the app, the plot gets updated with 110000 points.

```
library(sparklyr)

conf = spark_config()
conf$spark.driver.memory="50g"
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local[*]", config = conf)
read_folder <- stream_read_csv(sc, "hdfs://localhost:9000/nik_ml/")

ui <- function(){
  plotOutput("plot")
}

server <- function(input, output, session){

  ps <- reactiveSpark(read_folder, intervalMillis = 10)
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    df2 = ps()
    # str(df2)
    ggplot(data = df2, aes(x=Time, y=outletN2)) + geom_point() + ggtitle(nrow(df2)) + theme_bw()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)


SessionInfo()

# R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
# Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
# Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)
# 
# Matrix products: default
# 
# locale:
# [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
# [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
# [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    
# 
# attached base packages:
#   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
#   [1] shinyFiles_0.7.2    bindrcpp_0.2.2      dplyr_0.7.8         shiny_1.2.0         ggplot2_3.1.0      
# [6] future_1.10.0       sparklyr_0.9.3.9000
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#   [1] tidyselect_0.2.5 forge_0.1.9002   purrr_0.2.5      listenv_0.7.0    lattice_0.20-38  colorspace_1.3-2
# [7] generics_0.0.2   htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.2.0       base64enc_0.1-3  rlang_0.3.0.1    later_0.7.5     
# [13] pillar_1.3.0     glue_1.3.0       withr_2.1.2      DBI_1.0.0        dbplyr_1.2.2     bindr_0.1.1     
# [19] plyr_1.8.4       munsell_0.5.0    gtable_0.2.0     htmlwidgets_1.3  codetools_0.2-15 labeling_0.3    
# [25] httpuv_1.4.5     parallel_3.5.1   broom_0.5.1      r2d3_0.2.2       Rcpp_1.0.0       xtable_1.8-3    
# [31] openssl_1.1      promises_1.0.1   backports_1.1.2  scales_1.0.0     jsonlite_1.6     config_0.3      
# [37] fs_1.2.6         mime_0.6         digest_0.6.18    grid_3.5.1       rprojroot_1.3-2  tools_3.5.1     
# [43] magrittr_1.5     lazyeval_0.2.1   tibble_1.4.2     crayon_1.3.4     tidyr_0.8.2      pkgconfig_2.0.2 
# [49] rsconnect_0.8.12 assertthat_0.2.0 httr_1.4.0       rstudioapi_0.8   R6_2.3.0         globals_0.12.4  
# [55] nlme_3.1-137     compiler_3.5.1
```

But what I really want is to reactively read a single file at a time and make a ggplot. This is similar to Spark Streaming, but Spark Streaming (from what I understand) reads ALL text files into a single RDD. From Spark's documentation, there exist a function in Python called *SparkContext.wholeTextFiles* which lets you read a directory containing multiple small text files, and returns each of them as (filename, content) pairs ([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/programming-guide.html)). I haven't tested it as I want to keep everything in R right now. I looked into shinyFiles but couldn't find any function that does this  (https://github.com/thomasp85/shinyFiles).

Is there anything similar in R/Sparklyr? Is what I am trying to do sounds silly? If you think there is a more efficient way of achieving it in R, I am all ears!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way, with some help from @tricky. Full solution below. Dirty but works for now.

```
# Get list of current files in HDFS
files <- system("hadoop fs -ls /nik_ml", show.output.on.console = FALSE, intern = TRUE)
# Extract file names
fileNames <- na.omit(str_extract(files, "(?<=/)[^/]*$"))

# CheckFunc for reactivePoll, checks for changes in fileNames
listFiles <- function(){
  files <<- system("hadoop fs -ls /nik_ml", show.output.on.console = FALSE, intern = TRUE)
  fileNames <<- na.omit(str_extract(files, "(?<=/)[^/]*$"))
  fileNames
}

# ValueFunc for reactivePoll. Returns a vector of HDFS filepaths
ReadHdfsData=function(){ 
  path <- paste0("hdfs://localhost:9000/nik_ml/", fileNames)
  return(path)
}

ui3 <- function(){
  plotOutput("plot")
}

server3 <- function(input, output, session){

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    allFiles <- reactivePoll(5 * 1000, session, listFiles, ReadHdfsData)
    # Find filepaths which are added to HDFS
    newFile <<- setdiff(allFiles(), newFile)
    # print(newFile)
    # Do something with each new file. 
    # I am plotting currently, but I will end up using it for ML predictions.
    for(temp in newFile){
    df <- spark_read_csv(sc, "name", temp) %>%
      select(Time, outletN2) %>%
      collect()
    # print(head(df))
    p1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x=Time, y=outletN2)) + 
      geom_point() + 
      ggtitle(paste("File =",temp)) + 
      theme_bw()
    print(p1)
    }
  })
}
# Initialise newFile to "" before running the app
newFile <- character(0)
shinyApp(ui3, server3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had your issue during one of my project. What I ended up using was the reactivePoll function to update my plot.

So you have two options, either you update the plot every x seconds without knowing if there are new files. In this example 120 seconds so two minutes :
You initialize your accumulator b, at the start of the app code.

```
b <- 0

IsThereNew = function(){
  b <<- b+1
  b
}

ReadHdfsData=function(){ # A function that calculates the underlying value
  path <- paste0("/your/path/to/data.json")
  df <- sc %>%
    spark_read_json("name", path) %>%
    collect()
  return(df)
}

df <- reactivePoll(120 * 1000, session, IsThereNew, ReadHdfsData)
```

So in this case, in a dumb way, you update your plot every 2 minutes even if there are no new data.

The other way you can do is to list the number of files in the hdfs directory, every x seconds, and if the listing count is modified then the plot will be updated
So you'll have to define a function listNumberOfFiles which returns the number of files and replace the isThereNew function.

Comment: I tried the 2nd way of listing number of files. I started with one file in HDFS and it made a plot with 10000 points. When I added a 2nd file to HDFS, it read both the files and made a plot of 20000 points, which is not needed.

Comment: oh, you only want the second file to be plotted... That might be harder. But you could keep last_df in memory, read the full directory. And do a Spark DataFrame difference between the full_df and the last_df in memory ?

Comment: Yes, the idea is to plot "live" data as it comes into Hadoop. I was thinking of doing what you suggested, but it will be time consuming when it reaches hundred of files. I thought there would be a more straight-forward way.

Comment: Maybe you can list hdfs files, check for the path of the last file uploaded via its timestamp. Check if it is a new file by comparing it to your last read file. If yes, isThereNew increments and returns something new. So your readHdfsData will read the last hdfs file uploaded ? And the plot is re updated

Comment: I was thinking of this exact approach, by getting names of all files in hdfs before starting the app and once the app has started, to look for new file name. I just feel this should have been implemented in some function of Sparklyr by now.